# Sign in automation with a registration email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner to rails and I'm having trouble with signing users in when they click on the registration email. I'm calling a login method (sign_in) and then directing them to the a page in the site, but the logic does not work. I am using Sorcery for generating the activation email. My repo is [Here](https://github.com/latinforadapt/grmbly_app). I would appreciate any help, I'm a beginner still learning. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing magical about the *email* -- well, okay, it's probably got a [capability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security) tacked onto the end of an URL that lets you know the email address exists long enough to receive one email -- but once they sign in using your login method, it should store a cookie in the browser with a reference to the session id. (Or store session data directly in the cookie... up to you.)

So long as the same browser is used from the email clicking to the normal site use, the cookie (and its reference to the session id or session data) should still be valid, and they should still be "logged in".

Comment: My mistake that I didn't mention, but when they register, it does not sign them in. Rather I am sending an email, which requires them the activate by clicking on a link that is sent in that email. This activation is required before they sign in.

Comment: And when they type their username / passwd on the confirmation page, that's when you should give them the cookie...

Comment: That makes sense. I was hoping to work on the logic of having them automatically logged in when they click on the link, instead of having them re-enter their username/password.

Comment: I think you can make it login automatically on click of activation link, if you can find the user by the url parameters and create the session based on those parameters, but i think without passing password it would not be possible to create user session.

Comment: Ah! Now I get it. One downside is whoever gets a hold of that email could then use it to log in as the given user without having to know the user name and password. As @vicky suggests, look up the user based on the URL parameters, and create your new session that way. (Your `login` action will already have all the code for that -- just leave out the portions that verify password.) It would be a good idea to _time limit_ the URL in some way, so it can't be used again in six months...

Comment: I just looked into your repository, and found that you're actually storing the password in the clear, in the `self.salt` member: https://github.com/latinforadapt/grmbly_app/blob/master/app/models/user.rb -- _please_ do not use any portion of the password as the salt. Time alone should be useful enough as a brute-force cracking deterrent.

Comment: sarnold and vicky, thank you both for your help. I think I'm now on the right track.